# what is the issue with rapidminer hbos process ?

Tags: rapidminer

I have a dataset of more than 1 million transactions running on windows with 32 GB  RAM with HBOS algorithm.

The issue is we are getting an **Out of Memory** Error.
Can anyone help.

Comment: Hi, could you please give some more information about your data and the settings of the operator? I guess you are using the "Histogram-based Outlier Score (HBOS)" operator from the Anomaly Detection extension?

Comment: Hi David, the data consist's of features as follows: customer_id,msg_id,otherparty_id,sendingbank_id,amt,recevingbank_id,year,quarter,month,date_bin,day_bin, hour_bin with HBOS operator with parameter : parameter mode "all",no. of bins "-1", select mode "fixed bandwith"

Answer (score 0):

the HBOS algorithm can be quite memory intensive and the memory needed grows with the number of attributes used. So first of all, reducing the number of attributes might help.

But I couldn't reproduce your error. Perhaps you should reduce the max memory used by RapidMiner (under *Settings -> Preferences -> System*). The JVM always needs a slight overhead, so running RapidMiner with 30GB max memory should be safe.